# POST data to blazor component

Tags: blazor-webassembly

Is it possible for an external site to POST to a Blazor Component (.razor)?

When the client is on my apps' shopping cart page and clicks on payment, he is redirected to an external site handling the payment. The external site then sends back a post request to my Blazor (.razor) component, to the url as specified in my component: @page "/mysite/success". This POST request fails status code 400.

If I add IgnoreAntiforgeryToken to my host page (RAZOR Page .cshtml) then I can post to my blazor component.

```
@page "/_Host"
@namespace Client

@attribute [IgnoreAntiforgeryToken]

@{
    Layout = "_Layout";
}

@model HostModel

<component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="WebAssemblyPrerendered" />
```

But I do not want to disable CSRF for all the components. Only for the one component.

Thanks, Louise

Comment: You can't post to a `Component`, there's no such concept.  When your external site does it's call back, it posts to the server which then starts up a new blazor application.  You need to handle the call back in a different way.  Server or  WASM?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is. The trick to *accepting* the post is to include `IgnoreAntiforgeryToken` in the `_Host` page. The trick to reading the data is to catch the `OnPost` in the `PageModel`. The downfall is that Blazor is a single page application and the ignore attribute will be turned on globally.

I can't find an effective way to programmatically add the `IgnoreAntiforgeryToken` or change the `PageModel` for an individual page component. Instead I create a list of `PostComponentPages` that will accept post data.

Hopefully someone can build on this answer and find a better way to turn on `IgnoreAntiforgeryToken` for an individual component.

*Note: In my example I only accept post data to the Counter page.*

**_Host.cshtml**

```
@{
    Layout = "_Layout";
    @model HostPageModel;

}
```

**HostPageModel.cs**

```
// Required for accepting post data from 3rd party resource.
[IgnoreAntiforgeryToken]
// Not required, but gives us access to the post data and exception handling per request.
public class HostPageModel : PageModel
{
    /// <summary>
    /// A list of components we accept post request on.
    /// </summary>
    public static List<string> PostComponentPages =  new List<string>() { "/counter" };

    // postFormService is injected by the DI
    public HostPageModel(PostFormService postFormService)
    {
        PostFormService = postFormService;
    }

    private PostFormService PostFormService { get; }

    // Hook in to the OnPost.
    public void OnPost()
    {
       if (PostComponentPages.Any(c => Request.Path.ToString().Contains(c)))
           PostFormService.Form = Request.Form; // acceptable component, store the post form in the PostFormService
       else
           throw new Exception("HTTP 401 Error – Unauthorized");
    }

}
```

**PostFormService.cs**

Responsible for storing the post data in a service collection.

```
public class PostFormService
{
    public IFormCollection? Form { get; set; }
}
```

**Program.cs**

Register the service.

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<PostFormService>();
```

**Counter.razor**

Inject our service, and read the post data from third party.

```
@inject PostFormService PostFormService;
protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    base.OnInitialized();
    // These fields are based on the third party.
    var PaymentID = PostFormService.Form?["PaymentID"];
    var ReturnCode = PostFormService.Form?["ReturnCode"];
    var ReturnMessage = PostFormService.Form?["ReturnMessage"];
}
```

*Note: Just noticed this only works in `ServerPrerendered`.* Since the Post request is always treated as a new scope/session, I handle this by making the `_Host.cshtml` force `ServerPrerendered` for pages supporting Post requests.

```
@if (HostPageModel.PostComponentPages.Any(c => Request.Path.ToString().Contains(c)))
{
    <component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="ServerPrerendered" />
}
else
{
    <component type="typeof(App)" render-mode="Server" />
}
```

Comment: I tried the code. However, components' `OnInitialized()` hook is rendering twice and on the second time, the Form object is `null`.

Comment: @M.Ko That is why we use the null conditional operator `?` to access the form value. You could use an `if`; `if(PostFormService.Form != null) { doWork(PostFormService.Form); }` Generally I keep it simple, my postable page raises an event to some service when `PostFormService.Form` is not `null`.